# C Program returning a series of question marks at the end or sometimes, returning nothing

Tags: c, parsing, getchar

My program is supposed to erase /**/ comments, condense white spaces, and remove line splices of the input.

**edit: scroll down to problem update below.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ass(), f1(), f2(), f3();

int mainRunner();

int a, b;

int main() {
    ass();
    mainRunner();
}

void ass() {
    a = getchar();
    b = getchar();
}

int mainRunner() {
    while ( a != EOF ) {
        f1();
        f2();
        f3();
        putchar(a);
        a = b;
        b = getchar();
    }
}

// Removes Line Splices
void f1() {
    if ((a == '\\') && (b == '\n')) {
        a = getchar();
        b = getchar();
        mainRunner();
    }
}

//Removes Comments in the /*...*/ form
void f2() {
    if ((a == '/') && (b == '*')) {
        while ((a != '*') || (b != '/')) {
            a = b;
            b = getchar();
        }
        a = getchar();
        b = getchar();
        mainRunner();
    }
}

//Condenses White Spaces
void f3() {
    if ((a == ' ') && (b == ' ')) {
        a = b;
        b = getchar();
        mainRunner();
    }
}
```

When I run the testscript (testscript 1):

```
a b  c
d             e
f
g


hifealkfja;efa  faekjf;ale   feafaefa
```

This is returned

```
a b c
d e
f
g


hifealkfja;efa faekjf;ale feafaefa
????????????????
```

When I run this testscript (testscript 2):

```
start linesplice NOW!\
This should be connected with first line.Comment begins here:/*fjelajfal;efjael$
fe;ajfe;fe8/Comment Ends.
Series of 5 spaces between the letters:a     b
Series of 10 spaces between the letters:c          d
Increasing number of spaces between letters from 1 space:e f  g   h    i
```

Nothing happens and the command line cursor goes to the very left.

I appreciate any feedback, thanks.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Problem Update:
Reduced the issue above by doing what chux suggested. Now I only have the question mark problem. I made a fix so that putchars wouldn't be waiting in the stack and output a whole bunch of EOFs at the end, but why are there still two question marks? Here's my new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ass();

int mainRunner();

int a, b;

int main() {
    ass();
    mainRunner();
}

void ass() {
    a = getchar();
    b = getchar();
}

int mainRunner() {
    while ( a != EOF ) {
        // Removes Line Splices
        if ((a == '\\') && (b == '\n')) {
            a = getchar();
            b = getchar();
            mainRunner();
        }
        //Removes Comments in the /*...*/ form
        if ((a == '/') && (b == '*')) {
            while ((a != '*') || (b != '/')) {
                a = b;
                b = getchar();
            }
            a = getchar();
            b = getchar();
            mainRunner();
        }
        //Condenses White Spaces
        if ((a == ' ') && (b == ' ')) {
            a = b;
            b = getchar();
            mainRunner();
        }
        if (a == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            putchar(a);
            a = b;
            b = getchar();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the second test script from above (with an asterisk added to end the comment), my program outputs:

> start linesplice NOW!This should be connected with first line.Comment
>   begins here:Comment Ends. Series of 5 spaces between the letters:a b
>   Series of 10 spaces between the letters:c d Increasing number of
>   spaces between letters from 1 space:e f g h i ??

Notice the two question marks at the end. 
Note: the program works fine for the first test script.

Comment: Pray tell, what are `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` *supposed* to do?  And what about `ass`?

Comment: Rather than naming your function something non-descriptive (like `f1`) and using a comment to say what it does, why not just name it what it does (e.g. `removeLineSplices`)?

Comment: Never checking if getchar() succeeded? Only checking one time for EOF and making many many many unchecked getchars... This is doomed to fail.

Comment: I'll work on my style.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given OP's first testscript:

The `if` in `f1()` is never true.

The `if` in `f2()` is never true.

`f3()` effectively recurses into itself via `mainRunner()` when multiple space are encountered.  Upon seeing `EOF`, the recursion stops, and unwinds. `mainRunner()` performs `putchar(a);` with EOF in `a` with each unwinding.

---

Removing `mainRunner();` in `f1()`, `f2()`, & `f3()` may help.

The test code has 1 + 13 + 1 + 2 sequences of 2 spaces.  This causes 17 recursive calls.  Upon unwinding `putchar(EOF)` is called 16 times creating the `'?'`.

---

In OP's 2nd testscript. `f2()` gets into an infinite loop with

```
while ((a != '*') || (b != '/')) {
  a = b;
  b = getchar();
}
```

as there is no escape should `getchar()` return `EOF`.

Comment: Thank you so much! your response fixed everything. I wish I could up vote this answer, but I only have 8 reputation points. I'll up vote this as soon as I can.

Comment: @davidliuliuliu Note: I suspect the down-voter, who left no comment, did not find the initial answer satisfactory.

Comment: @davidliuliuliu You may want to use `int ungetc(int c, FILE *stream);`.  This negates the need to have global variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: it turns out the program still has a minor issue. I updated my  post. Could you take a look? I just started learning C yesterday so I'm not familiar with the code you suggested.

Comment: @davidliuliuliu 1) An inconsistency took way to much time to discern.  Your posted test-script_2 has `8/`, but apparently you did your test with `*/`.  2) Try code `putchar(a); printf("%d",a);` and report the last output,something like "g103 32h104 32i105\n10".  3) you still have infinite loop in `while ((a != '*') || (b != '/'))`.  suggest `while ((a != '*') || (b != '/')) { if (a == EOF) return 0;`. 4) There are still problems - I think stemming from the `mainRunner()` calls - suggest removing them and change `if ((a == ' ') && (b == ' '))` to `while ((a == ' ') && (b == ' '))`